# map(int, open(fn)) vs map(int, open(fn).readlines()) vs [int(x) for x in open(fn)]

Tags: python, list-comprehension, memory-profiling

*UPD: several questions is resolved.*

We have four realizations for file with 10**7 integers in file (one number - one line).

| Case | Code. Parameter `int=int` for non-using global scope |
| --- | --- |
| map | `def without_readlines(int=int):` `data = list(map(int, open('test.txt')))` |
| map + readlines | `def with_readlines(int=int):` `​data = list(map(int, open('test.txt').readlines()))` |
| list comprehension | `def without_readlines_listcomp(int=int):` `data = [int(x) for x in open('test.txt')]` |
| list comprehension + readlines | `def with_readlines_listcomp(int=int):` `data = [int(x) for x in open('test.txt').readlines()]` |

**First question by speed test:**

The code for the test of function is similar.

```
from timeit import default_timer
def func():
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = default_timer()
    func()
    print(default_timer() - st)
```

| without_readlines() | with_readlines() | without_readlines_listcomp() | with_readlines_listcomp() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.51-1.56 sec | 1.6-1.8 sec | 1.79-1.82 sec | 1.89-1.93 sec |

***1)** Why is the difference between list comparison variants and map variants 2-3 times? 0.2-0.3 vs 0.07-0.12*

**Second question by memory profiling.**

The code for the test of function is similar.

*UPD: This approach is not show deep memory usage for `map` function.*

```
from memory_profiler import profile
@profile
def func():
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
```

|  | Mem usage | Increment | Occurences | Line Contents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| without_readlines | 19.3 MiB 406.0 MiB | 19.3 MiB 386.7 MiB | 1 1 | @profile def without_readlines(int=int): data = list(map(int, open('test.txt'))) |
| with_readlines | 19.4 MiB 402.4 MiB | 19.4 MiB 383.0 MiB | 1 1 | @profile def with_readlines(int=int): data = list(map(int, open('test.txt').readlines())) |
| without_readlines listcomp | 19.4 MiB 402.5 MiB | 19.4 MiB -24068.2 MiB | 1 10000003 | @profile def without_readlines_listcomp(int=int): data = list(map(int, open('test.txt'))) |
| with_readlines listcomp | 19.4 MiB 1092.4 MiB | 19.4 MiB -4585.2 MiB | 1 10000003 | @profile def with_readlines_listcomp(int=int): data = list(map(int, open('test.txt').readlines())) |

***2)** Why difference between listcomp variants is more 600 MiB? It's memory for storage 10**7 strings?*

*Answer*: Yes, it's size of object with 10**7 strings (size of list + size of all string into this list).

```
from sys import getsizeof
strs = open('test.txt').readlines()
print(getsizeof(strs) + sum(map(getsizeof, strs)))
# 657 984 050
```

***3)** Why difference between map variants is less 85 MiB? 85 MiB - size of list with 10**7 strings.*

*Answer*: difference 86 MiB is size of list object with strings (result of `file.readlines()`). Not list + all strings into. Only list object.

```
from sys import getsizeof
print(getsizeof(open('test.txt').readlines()))
# 89 095 160
```

Defference in test not correct. Correct way to calculation memory usage for `map` function in next answer.

***4)** How map function work on low level? Why difference by memory is not similar for list comprehension functions?*

*Answer*: Becouse decorator `@profile` not show the memory usage for deep call.

For correct memory test I use next approach.

```
from memory_profiler import profile, memory_usage
start_mem = memory_usage(max_usage=True)
res = memory_usage(proc=(func), max_usage=True, include_children=True, retval=True)
print(res[0] - start_mem)
```

Results for that tests:

| with_readlines | without_readlines | with_readlines_listcomp | without_readlines_listcomp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1065-1164 MiB | 402-475 MiB | 1061-1124 MiB | 393-468 MiB |

Such data converge with the logic of working with python objects.

***5)** What do negative values for increment mean?*

Comment: `map` doesn't return a list, so you're not comparing the same things. And "without listcomp" is using list comprehension

Comment: sorry, list(map()). Checked this moment.

Comment: Answers don't belong into questions but into answers.

Answer (score 1):

First, `readlines()` allocates a list into memory, and therefore requires a function call before the actual data can be iterated; it needs to iterate the entire file, then return, then your code runs. Iterating over a file directly doesn't do that. This explains why it takes longer (although not 3x like you say)

Secondly, map function returns a generator, so either you need to do `(int(x) for x...)` - a generator expression. Or do `list(map(int, open(...))`- convert to a list for a real comparison.

Last, you should be using `with` to close the file handles

```
with open("file") as f:
    list(map(int, f))
```

And make sure you run your profiler several times, and take the average... I'm not sure why negative numbers would appear for memory usage. The `Occurences` value seems to also have something to do with the increased memory usage

Comment: I'm checked moment with convertation to list.

Comment: Question for defference by memory. Why difference less? I think that `readlines()` return all strings from file.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Profiling has been several times

Comment: Size of file - 83 MiB. Memory for 10**8 strings more. Why difference between tests only 4 MiB?